# SQL Server Stored Procedure - Can I do multiple things in a single procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

So, as before I'm trying to relearn a bunch of stuff...and learn some new stuff. I used to do some Stored Procedure work in my youth and I could have sworn I created Stored Procedures that had "methods" within in a single procedure. I could then reference that procedure and call a method.

Either that or I'm losing my mind.

So the question is, is it possible to have a single stored procedure that has multiple methods that can be called from C#? Or is it just better (and seems to be simpler) to have a single stored procedure for each "action" that I need to take with a database?

Comment: Depending on permissions of course, you can do anything you want in a stored procedure.

Comment: Can you write a C# application contained of a single huge method with "action" argument and dozens of `if` statements? Would it be a good style?

Comment: Very good point @IvanStarostin

Comment: One thing to consider is if you wish everything to happen in a single transaction (meaning that either everything, or nothing happens). This to make sure the database stays consistent. Although there are multiple ways to make sure everything occurs in a single transaction (with an ORM like EntityFramework or with a Stored Procedure in the database).

Comment: And it is not only a matter of style here, but also efficiency (performance). Pass option 1 in first param to do the "first block" and NULL for the parameters that are to be served as input for block 2, 3, 4... Say that this is an exec that brings the proc in cache. Now the proc is optimized based on the values passed into the proc, and it will probably totally mess upp calculated selectivity for block 2, 3, 4.... Aka, parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not recommended but I had seen an amateur developer(used to frequently complete projects for fiverr and freelancer) do something of this kind.
The person had a single storedprocedure which used to take in first variable as action to perform and a second paramter which took stringified json object for data. Based on IF logic on action, sp would determine what to do.

His reasoning for this was:

1. Person had a simple application and there was no reason to create simple CRUD stored procedures.
2. Any changes were done to a single SP, so if anything breaks he knows where to look for.

Not that I recommend but it is doable. That's beauty of SQL.